# Installing Opencv3 in Python on Mac error

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am trying to install Opencv 3 for Python on Mac using this link (https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-opencv-3-for-python-on-mac/)

I am using python 3.6.4 and I am currently at step 6 (regarding the link)

I am using Python directly from the Mac terminal and when I slot in the following command this error appears:

```
$ ln -S /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ln -S /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Do you have the directory `3.4.0_1` under `opencv` directory?

Comment: It is a lower case `s` you need, i.e.`ln -s ...`

Comment: How would I make sure that I have the directory 3.4.0_1 under opencv? @SudheeshSinganamalla

Comment: I have used a lower case s and the problem still occurs. @MarkSetchell

Comment: `cd /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/` and then do `ls` to check the directory name?

Comment: You can find the file you want with `find  /usr/local/Cellar/opencv  -name "cv2.cpython*so"`

Comment: Louiss-MacBook-Pro:~ louisduplessis$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/
Louiss-MacBook-Pro:opencv louisduplessis$ ls
3.4.0_1
Louiss-MacBook-Pro:opencv louisduplessis$ find /usr/local/Cellar/opencv -name "cv2.cpython*so"
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Louiss-MacBook-Pro:opencv louisduplessis$  @SudheeshSinganamalla

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need to run a command like:

```
ln -s SRC TGT
```

where `SRC` is the library you have just built/installed and `TGT` is where you want it to be visible to Python.

---

Find the `SRC` file, independently of the OpenCV versions you have installed, like this:

```
SRC=$(find /usr/local/Cellar/opencv -name "cv2.cpython*so")
```

and check it looks correct with:

```
echo "$SRC"
```

There should be one line. If there is more than one line, it means you have multiple versions of OpenCV installed, so it may look like:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.1_7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

In that case, choose the one you want and manually set `SRC` to that one, e.g.

```
SRC=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

---

Find the TGT directory, independently of the Python versions you have installed, like this:

```
TGT=$(find /usr/local/lib/ -type d -name "site-packages")
```

and check it looks correct with:

```
echo "$TGT"
```

There should be one line. If there is more than one line, it means you have multiple versions of Python installed, and it may look something like:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

If that is the case, choose the one you want to use and set `TGT` manually, e.g.:

```
TGT=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

---

Now make the link:

```
ln -s "$SRC" "$TGT/cv2.so"
```

Answer (score 0):

In step 6, you first get the `sys` path, notice that this is done while running python.

You can tell because of the prompt ">>>" in

```
>>> print(sys.path)
```

If you then enter:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_4/....
```

While in Python, you will get the exact error you mentioned.

In order to finish step 6 you now must exit python by typing

```
>>> exit()
```

Now you will see the `$` prompt.

I realize the way you stated your problem that you were already at the `$` prompt, so this might be moot... but if you typed your question rather than cutting and pasting it, maybe you typed it incorrectly here and you were actually still in Python when you had the error.

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! please the next time use the brackets in the editor to format your code, I've done it for you this time.